# Laravel Query builder returns a row from join instead of multiples row

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am getting fewer results than expected , The data returns 57 rows instead of 70 rows. I need help to get all the rows please, I returned a collection using get(), and i joined it with foreach() to include the rows to existing query, Please any help?

```
   public function getempAttendance(Request $request) {
        $id = $request->id;
        $department_id = $request->department_id;

        if($id !== null){                                                       //return based on type;
            $emp = AsEmployee::where('id','=',$id)->orderBy('id','ASC')->get();
        } else if($department_id != null){
            $emp = AsEmployee::where('department_id','=',$department_id)->orderBy('id','ASC')->get();
        } else{                                                                 //return all if nothing is given;
            $emp = AsEmployee::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        }                                                   
        foreach($emp as $emp_data){
            $department = AsDepartment::where('id','=',$emp_data->department_id)->get(['department'])->first();
            if($department !== NULL){
                $emp_data->department_name = $department->department;
            }else{
                $emp_data->department_name = '';
            }
            $position = AsEmployeePosition::where('id','=',$emp_data->position_id)->get(['position_name'])->first();

            if($position !== NULL){
            $emp_data->position_name = $position->position_name;
        }else{
            $emp_data->position_name = '';
        }
        $attendances = AsAttendanceLog::select('CHECK_IN_TIME','CHECK_OUT_TIME')
                                    ->where('EMPLOYEE_ID','=',$emp_data->employee_id)->get();
         if($attendances !== NULL){
            foreach($attendances as $attendance){
                $emp_data->CHECK_IN_TIME = Carbon::parse($attendance->CHECK_IN_TIME)->toTimeString();
                $emp_data->CHECK_OUT_TIME = Carbon::parse($attendance->CHECK_OUT_TIME)->toTimeString();
                $emp_data->Date = Carbon::parse($attendance->CHECK_IN_TIME)->format('Y-m-d');
                $hours = Carbon::parse($attendance->CHECK_OUT_TIME)->diffInSeconds(Carbon::parse($attendance->CHECK_IN_TIME));
                $emp_data->Hours = gmdate('H:i', $hours);
            }
        }else {
            $emp_data->CHECK_IN_TIME = '';
            $emp_data->CHECK_OUT_TIME = '';
        }
    }
    return  $this->sendResponse($emp);
}
```

Meanwhile, this works but i need the query builder format to allow me use Carbon and do some operations

```
$attendanceData = DB::table('as_tbl_employee_master AS emp')
                                ->leftJoin('as_tbl_department AS dept','emp.department_id','=', 'dept.id')
                                ->leftJoin('as_tbl_employee_position AS pos', 'emp.position_id', '=', 'pos.id')
                                ->leftJoin('as_tbl_emp_attendance_daily_log AS att', 'att.EMPLOYEE_ID', '=', 'emp.employee_id')
                                ->select('emp.id','emp.employee_id','emp.english_name','dept.department','pos.position_name','att.CHECK_IN_TIME','att.CHECK_OUT_TIME')
                                ->orderby('att.CHECK_IN_TIME', 'DESC')
                                ->get();

    return $this->sendResponse($attendanceData);
```

Comment: lookup using joins in lavavel. If you fetching, and then retrieving based on that fetch, or doing a query in a loop, you aren't using SQL to is maximum benefit. Startments like 57 rows instead of 70 rows or fewer rows than expecting don't help much. What exactly are you expecting (in real terms rather than rows)?

Comment: okay, Thank you, I am actually using query builder to join three tables, employee, department and attendance tables,  but the (attendance table) contains multiples rows with the same employee ID. So the query is just fetching just one row with employee ID, instead of multiple rows with same employee ID. I hope you would understand this. I am getting this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the user's table is "one to many" to as_tbl_emp_attendance_daily_log's table.
You should select('as_tbl_emp_attendance_daily_log') first then left join to user's table.

I assumed that you want to show all as_tbl_emp_attendance_daily_log's row. If that right your Query builder should be like this.

```
$attendanceData = DB::table('as_tbl_emp_attendance_daily_log AS att')
                            ->leftJoin('as_tbl_employee_master AS emp', 'att.EMPLOYEE_ID', '=', 'emp.employee_id')
                            ->leftJoin('as_tbl_department AS dept','emp.department_id','=', 'dept.id')
                            ->leftJoin('as_tbl_employee_position AS pos', 'emp.position_id', '=', 'pos.id')
                            ->select('emp.id','emp.employee_id','emp.english_name','dept.department','pos.position_name','att.CHECK_IN_TIME','att.CHECK_OUT_TIME')
                            ->orderby('att.CHECK_IN_TIME', 'DESC')
                            ->get();
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to add the custom attribute to the model you should define it at the model.
This is for reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

But you can directly change the attribute if you change the collections to the array first.

I don't have your table, so I cannot test it, I just changed it based on your snippet.

```
public function getempAttendance(Request $request) {
    $id = $request->id;
    $department_id = $request->department_id;

    if($id !== null){                                                       //return based on type;
        $emp = AsEmployee::where('id','=',$id)->orderBy('id','ASC')->toArray();
    } else if($department_id != null){
        $emp = AsEmployee::where('department_id','=',$department_id)->orderBy('id','ASC')->toArray();
    } else{                                                                 //return all if nothing is given;
        $emp = AsEmployee::orderBy('id','DESC')->toArray();
    }      


    for($i=0;$i < count($emp); $i++){
        $department = AsDepartment::where('id','=',$emp[$i]->department_id)->get(['department'])->first();
        if($department !== NULL){
            $emp[$i]['department_name'] = $department->department;
        }else{
            $emp[$i]['department_name'] = '';
        }
        $position = AsEmployeePosition::where('id','=',$emp[$i]['position_id'])->get(['position_name'])->first();

        if($position !== NULL){
        $emp[$i]['position_name'] = $position->position_name;
    }else{
        $emp[$i]['position_name'] = '';
    }
    $attendances = AsAttendanceLog::select('CHECK_IN_TIME','CHECK_OUT_TIME')
                                ->where('EMPLOYEE_ID','=',$emp[$i]['employee_id'])->toArray();
     $attendances_data = [];
     if($attendances !== NULL){
        for($j=0;$j<count($attendances);$j++){
            $data = [];
            $data['CHECK_IN_TIME'] = Carbon::parse($attendance['i']['CHECK_IN_TIME'])->toTimeString();
            $data['CHECK_OUT_TIME'] = Carbon::parse($attendance['i']['CHECK_OUT_TIME'])->toTimeString();
            $data['Date'] = Carbon::parse($attendance['i']['CHECK_IN_TIME'])->format('Y-m-d');
            $hours = Carbon::parse($attendance['i']['CHECK_OUT_TIME'])->diffInSeconds(Carbon::parse($attendance['i']['CHECK_IN_TIME']));
            $data['Hours'] = gmdate('H:i', $hours);
            $attendances_data[] = $data
        }
        $emp[$i]['attendances'] = $attendances_data;
    }else {
        $emp[$i]['attendances'] = [];
        $emp[$i]['attendances'] = [];
    }
}
return  $this->sendResponse($emp);
```

}

**UPDATE**
If you want to multiple row, I think you should try this:

```
$attendanceData = DB::table('as_tbl_emp_attendance_daily_log AS att')
                            ->leftJoin('as_tbl_employee_master AS emp', 'att.EMPLOYEE_ID', '=', 'emp.employee_id')
                            ->leftJoin('as_tbl_department AS dept','emp.department_id','=', 'dept.id')
                            ->leftJoin('as_tbl_employee_position AS pos', 'emp.position_id', '=', 'pos.id')
                            ->select('emp.id','emp.employee_id','emp.english_name','dept.department','pos.position_name','att.CHECK_IN_TIME','att.CHECK_OUT_TIME')
                            ->orderby('att.CHECK_IN_TIME', 'DESC')
                            ->toArray();
for($i=0;$i<count($attendaceData);$i++)
{
    $attendaceData[$i]['CUSTOM VARIABLE'] = 'NEW VALUE CUSTOM VARIABLE AT HERE';
}

return  $this->sendResponse($emp);
```

Comment: That's not the case, the query i mentioned worked well, but i want to use query builder i shared previously to solve this problem. The problem is if i use query builder to perform the query, it just returns one row in a one to many relationship instead of many rows with same ID.  I think i am suppose to return a collection from the many table (AsAttendanceLog) and combine it to the existing record using foreach, but its giving me issues. I would need help or clue about it please

Comment: That what I want to explain to you, if you want to select all as_tbl_emp_attendance_daily_log row and relating to the user's table, you should select as_tbl_emp_attendance_daily_log then left join to user's table.

If you select user's table first then left join to as_tbl_emp_attendance_daily_log
You will only get all users and 1 row each user.

Did you tried my Query builder?

Comment: yes, i tried the query builder and it returned just one row, Please, check the code snippet i shared the first time, i did the query builder and i think where i am missing it is where the "AsAttendanceLog" returns a collection, I need to get the values from the collection and push to my existng data using foreach loop, But i dont know how to go about it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the clue, I actually did some modifications based on this and i am getting the right result. You are great!!

Comment: Thanks for your help, the data from the code is actually returning an another array (attendances) inside the object. I need the data to be joined to the old array and not create a new attendance array i.e. the check_in_time, check_out_time should be part of the object and not create a different array, With this i can have different check_in_time and check_out_time for the same IDs

Comment: @Francis you should provide the JSON that you expected.

Comment: i added an illustration to the update you provided, Please help out, Thanks

Comment: Well, so my first answer will match your expectation then. 
You just need to change it to the array and assign new variable to it. I update my answer